# again: Call to a member function setTimezone() on a non-object

Tags: php, datetime, object

I suddenly get the error message `Fatal error: Call to a member function setTimezone() on a non-object` after adding some new lines of code:

first of all, i used DateTime to switch between different timeformats to calculate DST, etc.

I  used the following code [Code Block 1]

```
foreach ($result as $k=>$v)
    {$timestamp=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', $k,new DateTimeZone("UTC"));    //take current date from $k as new DateTile Object
         $timestamp->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));   //convert timezone
         $date[]=$timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');   // "export" the date to date-array
         }
```

This code works well, until now:

I added 20 code lines above an other DateTime function [Code Block 2]:

```
$ts=new DateTime("@".round($_GET['startdate']/1000));
$startdate=$ts->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z');
```

After I added these 2 lines, all the time i get the error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function setTimezone()`for this line:`$timestamp->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));`

...but i can't see an relation / connection between these to code parts?!

What's happened here?

Thank you, for any idea.

//Update: as you can see at the comments, i'm using PHP 5.3.6
again: the code block 1 works, if i remove the code block 2

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? DateTime objects were added after PHP 5.2.0 - http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: What happens when you do a `var_dump($timestamp);`?

Comment: `var_dump($timestamp)` before you set the timezone. What do you get? `createFromFormat` was only added to PHP in 5.3.

Comment: @Treffynnon the output of the dump is: bool(false). I use PHP 5.3.6. 
but way, because var_dump($timestamp) returned an object before adding these 2 lines....

Comment: You see in the doc how much your php version makes differences so maybe you could tell what php version you're using ?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the other two lines you have identified and the problem lies where @vsuskov has mentioned below.

Comment: this one looks [well related to your point](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#99309)

Comment: @hornetbzz, yes, it looks like... i have removed the timezone parameter, which is optional: $timestamp=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', $k);
$timestamp->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')); ...but there is still the same problem/error

Comment: @Treffynnon .... maybe - but why does it work, when removing code block 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like not all of array keys of `$result` is valid date strings. The DateTime class returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure. And when `$k` is not valid, `$timestamp` is false, which is not an object.

Comment: ok, interesting idea... i will try to verify that...but $k should be valid all the time.. i will check..

Comment: no, that's not the point. the error rises in the first element, where $k="2010-12-02T02:27:51Z", which is valid.

Comment: i double checked your hint.. and...yeah: you are right! I was wrong. $k="2010-12-02T02:27:51Z" is not valid, because: by looking at the format 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z' ".u" is missing, the milliseconds. Right format would be: $k="2010-12-02T02:27:51.000Z"  I think, that's happened,  because code block 2 generates a different $k as before.